# Displaying navigation title of detail view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to display navigation bar title of `DetailView` initially shown on SwiftUI enabled Master-Detail App.

[image]

When I use Storyboard based template, title of detail view is shown like this as expected.

[image]

Adding `.navigationBarTitle()` to `DetailView` has no effect.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var dates = [Date]()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MasterView(dates: $dates)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Master"))
                .navigationBarItems(
                    leading: EditButton(),
                    trailing: Button(
                        action: {
                            withAnimation { self.dates.insert(Date(), at: 0) }
                        }
                    ) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                )
            DetailView()
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Foo")) // Added this
        }.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

How can I do this with SwiftUI?

Comment: Hello, @fish potato Do you mind adding a runnable code instead of above one.

Coz in above one we have to assume so stuff to make it runnable

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is a part of code which `Master-Detail App` template generates from Xcode 11. Just one line was added to it.

Answer (score 0):

One you select something to show detail will show detail view with title
i compiled it with your code

check it out[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I want to do is, display title bar of detail view which is shown initially after launch.